# Marketing Cloud Portfolio component looks different between BUs; is broken in one

Tags: marketing-cloud, content

We use Portfolio to host all our images - due to what we perceive as many outstanding bugs we do not use the new 'content builder' interface - and it works fine in our parent Business Unit.

However, we have a child BU in which portfolio both looks completely different and does not show any images. When you click the image to view it, you get a DNS error with a 'site could not be found' type message. Does anyone know why the portfolio would have a different interface?

Comment: This sounds like you may have a different or mis-configured Authenticated Domain or Sender Authentication Package (SAP) for that business unit alone.  I would recommend reaching out to your Success Manager or SFMC Support to have them confirm that settings for the BU are as they should be.  

Your images will be hosted under your SAP domain unless otherwise specified and it's possible that BU just didn't get configured with the SAP (at least not completely).

Comment: Thanks @TonyToubia, I had a support call with Salesforce and the support analyst could see all the images, so it looks like an issue at our end.